# PHP/SQL Cycle items every x minutes

Tags: php, sql, timer, cycle, countdown

I have a friend who runs an online auction website. He currently has a featured items section on the homepage that he wants to have cycle an item every X amount of minute. The site runs off a MySQL database which I haven't actually seen yet.

The current code that he is using is a big, long messy Javascript code that is causing all kinds of errors.

The items would have to cycle in order and when they get to the end, go back and repeat again.

What would be the best approach to take to this using PHP?

EDIT: I mean from a backend SQL perspective. Not the UI.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Are you asking how to cycle it from a UI perspective, or how to select the appropriate "next" record from the DB?

Comment: Does page show the same item to all visitors during the interval, or does each visitor start the sequence from the beginning?

Comment: Also, does the page need to refresh the featured item automatically (i.e. if the user simply leaves the page open), or is it only done when the page is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse Xepoch,
I meant how to select the appropriate next record. I was thinking earlier (I hope I can explain this) of creating a new table that holds the id number of the current featured item in the SQL DB and then using the SHOW_TABLE_STATUS command to get the last updated time and then adding x amount of time on it to cycle it to the next record. So essentially it would be going 'if current featured item is older than the last updated time plus x minutes then update the id to the next one'. I think that makes sense...

Thanks
Ben

Comment: In response to your questions J. The same item would be shown to all visitors, I don't think it would be critical to have the page refresh automatically although I would consider it if it wasn't overly difficult.

Comment: This is a UI thing, nothing to do with the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a separate table for the featured items (probably has an item ID referencing the main items table and maybe other info)...  In this table, add a `last_featured` column to represent the time the item was last shown.  From there, you can manipulate your queries to get a rotating list of featured items.

It might look something like this (as a weird pseudocode mix between PHP & MYSQL):

```
// select the most recent item in the list, considered the current item
$item = SELECT * FROM featured_items ORDER BY last_featured DESC LIMIT 1;

if ($item['last_featured'] > X_minutes_ago) {
    // select the oldest item in the list, based on when it was last featured
    $item = SELECT * FROM featured_items ORDER BY last_featured ASC LIMIT 1;

    // update the selected item so it shows as the current item next request
    UPDATE featured_items SET last_featured=NOW() WHERE item_id = $item['item_id'];
}
```

Note that this requires 3 call to the database...  There may be a more efficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: Thanks mate,
I'll see how it goes!